# Pass to a txt file unique rows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pass unique rows to a txt file after doing a web scraping for certain values. So the txt file involves the following:

```
Current date                        Amount Gained
15/07/2017                                     660
16/07/2017                                    -200
17/07/2017                                     300
```

So basically what I want to do is to write a script that only allows unique rows I dont want any duplicates because values change daily. So if a user by accident runs the script two times in one day I dont want a duplicate row in my txt file because it will affect further calculations in my data analysis. So this is the function that I currently have and I will like to know what modifications should I make?

```
def Cost_Revenues_Difference():

    nrevenue = revenue
    ndifference = difference
    dateoftoday = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    Net_Result.append(nrevenue)

    with open('Net_Result.txt', 'a') as ac:
        for x in Net_Result:
            ac.write('\n' + dateoftoday + ' ' + str(Net_Result))


Cost_Revenues_Difference()
```

Comment: I highly recommend structured data like this be stored in csv or excel files for easy manipulation.

Comment: Can you change the order of the dates (i.e. have them in a descending order)? Or use a separate file to store the checked dates so you don't have to parse the whole file just to check the dates?

Comment: If the script was accidentally run multiple times, how should duplicates be handled? Ignore changes to previous dates? For example, if someone actually does run a script twice on the same day, would you take the one that was recorded a few hours earlier? Or closer to the end of day? etc

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. Two alternative ways described below.

## 1  (this alt updates the value)

One is to put them in a dictionary with key and value in pairs and use the json library to import and export data (benefit: very common data structure).

```
import json

with open("test.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

data["18-05-17"] = 123

with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=4)
```

Test.json

```
{
    "18-05-17": 123,
    "17-05-17": 123
}
```

As a dictionary only can hold unique keys you won't have duplicates.

## 2 (this alt will not update the value)

Another solution that comes in mind is put the current date in the filename:

```
import datetime
import os

today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%y%m%d")
filedate = [i for i in os.listdir() if i.startswith("Net_result")][0]

# If today is different than the filedate continue
if today != os.path.splitext(filedate)[0].split("_")[-1]:
    # code here
    with open(filedate, "a") as f:
        f.write('\n' + dateoftoday + ' ' + str(Net_Result))

    # rename
    os.rename(filedate,"Net_result_{}.csv".format(today))
```

You could start with a file with yesterdays date ("Net_result_170716") and the code would check if the file-ending is different from today (which it is) and add new value, rename file and save. Running the code again would not do anything (not even open the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can read all data of your file into list before:

```
with open('Net_Result.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

Then check if the line you want to add does not exist in your content list, if not, add that line to file:

```
newLine = dateoftoday + ' ' + str(Net_Result);
if not newLine in content:
    ac.write('\n' + newLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is affordable to be loaded into RAM and has the structure you given in the example lines, maybe dump the data as a python object into `.pkl`. For example:

```
import pickle
data = {'15/07/2017': 660,
        '16/07/2017': -200,
        '17/07/2017': 300}
with open('/path/to/the/file.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)
```

`pickle` files are friendly for python objects, you can utilise dictionary object's built-in methods to avoid redundant entries or make updates.

For more complicate structures, take a look at `pandas.Dataframes`. If your program works with languages other than python, `json` or `xml` might be better choices.